# Need to get the value which present under double quotes

Tags: java, selenium

Search with word `Food`, but after searching it is displaying under double quotes as `"Food"`.

Used.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("")).getText();
```

`HTML`:

```
<header class="search-top"> 
    <h1 id="results_header" class="home genrecontainer"> Search Results for 
        <span>"food"</span> 
    </h1> 
</header>
```

[image]

Comment: <header class="search-top">
<h1 id="results_header" class="home genrecontainer">
Search Results for
<span>"food"</span>
</h1>
</header>

Comment: Do you need the text only, of text with double quotes ?

Comment: you want `food` or `"food"`???

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473155/how-to-get-data-between-quotes-in-java
From your command you get the String and this and you need to get the string inside the quotes to which answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the text under **span** tag:

```
String searchKey = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#results_header > span")).getText();
```

Now, use replaceAll() method to remove quotes:

```
String yourDesiredValueWithoutQuotes = searchKey.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html it is difficult to provide you with an xpath that achieves this. You can just use Javas `subString()` method to achieve this:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='results_header']/span")).getText();
String trimmedText = text.subString(1, text.length()-1);
```

Comment: <header class="search-top">
<h1 id="results_header" class="home genrecontainer">
Search Results for
<span>"food"</span>
</h1>
</header>

Comment: @karthikashoka i think the approach i suggested above is best. getText() returns a string value and java makes it easy to manipulate strings with its built in methods.

Comment: k how to get only text which is between double quotes

Comment: want value as food

Comment: ya checked but value food displaying with quotes(i.e "food"). required value only as food without quotes

Comment: the second line of my example creates a substring with the quotes removed.