# Replace characters in a String, in a specific location

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have the following string;

```
String s = "Hellow world,how are you?\"The other day, where where you?\"";
```

And I want to replace the `,` but only the one that is inside the quotation mark \"The other day, where where you?\".

Is it possible with regex?

Comment: suppose this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473155/how-to-get-data-between-quotes-in-java) is about getting the words inside quotes.

Comment: what do you want to replace it with?

Comment: Anything, for example *

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "Hellow world,how are you?\"The other day, where where you?\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    s = s.substring(0, matcher.start()) + matcher.group().replace(',','X') + 
            s.substring(matcher.end(), s.length());                                  
}
```

If there are more then two quotes this splits the text into in quote/out of quote and only processes inside quotes. However if there are odd number of quotes (unmatched quotes), the last quote is ignored.

Comment: This is a good answer.  If you change the regexp from `\"(.*)\"` to `\"([^\"]*)\"`, it will work for multiple pairs of quotes also.

Comment: @msandiford I used `.*?` (reluctant matcher), that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure this is always the last "," you can do that

```
String s = "Hellow world,how are you?\"The other day, where where you?\"";
int index = s.lastIndexOf(",");
if( index >= 0 )
    s = new StringBuilder(s).replace(index , index + 1,"X").toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nop, i'm not sure if the "," is the last, thanks for the help.

Comment: then look for "day," instead of only ","