# convert String to ArrayList with removing extra "" signs

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, stream

I have a `String abc="a","b","c";`
I want to convert it to `ArrayList`. 
I am converting it using this code.

`List<String> list11 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(abc.split(" , ")));`

Currently, output is coming like this

```
"subCategory": ["\"a\"", "\"b\"","\"c\""],`
```

I want to have output like this:

```
["a","b","c"]
```

Comment: Post a complete minimal example, as code. Your posted code is not formatted as code, and is invalid Java. Also post the desired and actual output as code.

Comment: I have already pasted code.

Comment: Read my edited comment.

Comment: you can use a map on the result and remove the quotes taking help from this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473155/how-to-get-data-between-quotes-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Given `String abc="\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"";`

You can simply replace the quotation marks within the `String` before using `split()`:

```
 List<String> list11 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(abc.replace("\"", "").split(",")));
```

***Output:***

```
[a, b, c]
```

Comment: `new ArrayList` seems superfluous here. Why would you want to make a mutable copy of an output that is already correct?

Comment: @Dici The OP said they wanted to convert it to an `ArrayList`

Comment: Mmm, true, didn't see that. I maintain that it should only be done if a mutable output is required though (actually `Arrays.asList` returns a list that is not structurally mutable - can't add or remove elements - but is still modifiable - can re-assign an existing value - so it's already not immutable).

Answer (score 0):

your string must be like below format so you can easily get 
["a","b","c"]

```
String abc="\"a\""+","+"\"b\""+",\"c\"" ;
List list11 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(abc.split(" , ")));
System.out.println(list11);
```