# Find content between both single and double quotes with PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, text, quotes

```
My text "can contain" both single 'and double"' quotes. The quotes "can also be 'nested" as you can see.
```

### Expected results

(array with 3 items)

```
can contain
and double"
can also be 'nested
```

### How far I've come

I'm not a regex expert, far from it. I still managed to get text between double quotes like `I can "grab this" text`.

```php
preg_match_all("~\"(.*?)\"~", $text, $between);
print_r($between);
```

### Valid / invalid

- Valid: `This is "A text"` (A text)
- Valid: `This is 'A text'` (A text)
- Valid: `This is "A 'text"` (A 'text)
- Valid: `This is 'A "text'` (A "text)
- Invalid: `This is "A text` (Uneven quotes 1)
- Invalid: `This is 'A text` (Uneven quotes 1)
- Invalid: `This is "A "text"` (Uneven quotes 3)
- Invalid: `This is 'A 'text'`(Uneven quotes 3)
- Invalid: `This "is ' A " text'` (Intersecting)

### Additional notes

- If there is an error, like a non closed quote, it's fine if it breaks (`This "has "one wrong" quote`)
- I would prefer a regex solution, but if there are better non regex solutions, it's fine.

### My guesses

My guess is that each character needs to be looped and checked. If it starts with a `"`, it needs to step the characters to the next `"` in order to wrap it in. Then I guess it's need to be reset from that position to see what the next type of quote is and to it again until the string has ended.

### Answers on Stackoverflow that does not work

This answer does **not** work for my problem:
[regex match text in either single or double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967465/regex-match-text-in-either-single-or-double-quote)

A proof can be seen here: https://regex101.com/r/OVdomu/65/

Comment: @NigelRen No, it did not. I updated his demo and it wraps almost all of the string so that works differently than I'm hoping for. https://regex101.com/r/OVdomu/65/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tested your regex here: https://regex101.com/r/WSaYeh/1/ I was surpriced how well it works. I tried to make it break, but could not. Do you see any pitfalls with it?

Comment: The `preg_match_all('~(?|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\')~', $txt, $matches); print_r($matches[1]);` breaks with your invalid (Uneven quotes) cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If it's invalid, it's broken anyway so that's fine for me. You can add it as an answer if you like.

Comment: How should it handle *intersecting* sections? E.g.: `...A " B ' C " D ' E...` ?

Comment: @Yoshi Very good point as I did not cover that case in my question. In my case, it should be seen as invalid and work like the answer by Wiktor (`B ' C` as first part then break or skip).

Comment: @JensTörnell Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58339041/5527985) is of help as well ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/fMkRzQ/3)). It also deals with escaped quotes inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\')~', $txt, $matches)) { 
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h0TEQn/1/) and the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/RtMXf).

A variation that supports escaped quotes, too:

```
'~(?|"([^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"|\'([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*)\')~s'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h0TEQn/2).

The `(?|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\')` is a [**branch reset group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) matching either `"`, then any 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"` or a `'`, then any 0+ chars other than `'` and then `'`, while capturing into Group 1 all the contents between the matching quotation marks.

Comment: I use the first one. As far as I know, it works for all my cases and it's much shorter. The variation looks more lika a hack than a regex. But good to have alternatives, especially for others visiting this question in the future.