# How to get data between quotes that isn't surrounded by parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse actionscript files and I'm trying figure out a regex that determines whether a line contains a string but at the same time that string isn't a parameter of a function.

So something like this would be fine and return "derping around" without quotes.

```
_root.bun = "derping around";
```

This would also be fine and return "(derping around with parentheses)" without quotes

```
_root.bun = "(derping around with parenthesis)";
```

This is no good as the quotes are surrounded by parentheses so we return nothing.

```
gotoAndPlay("derp");
```

I was looking at this question and while the answer solves a good chunk of my problem I don't know how I'm supposed to change it to check if theres parentheses around the quotes. Here's the link.

[how to get data between quotes in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473155/how-to-get-data-between-quotes-in-java)

Any help would be appreciated as I've been stuck on this for over a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should find the values you're looking for:

```
[^(]\".*\"
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/oCT1V1/1

Comment: Nice, though I suggest `.*?` or `[^"]*` instead of `.*`, so as to ensure that matching ends at the _very next_ `"`